# Pointer to pointer to variable of struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have :

```
typedef struct a{  
    int var;  
}aa;


typedef struct b{
    aa *a;
}bb;

int main()
{   
    
    bb *b;
    b->a->var;
    return 0;
}
```

`struct a` nested in `b`.
How to initialize value for variable `var` using `2` pointers like this:
`b->a->var;`
?

Comment: Struct a is not nested in b (i.e. a part of b), it is just pointed by some member of b (one of many pointer members, potentially).

Answer (score 5):

1. Initialize `b` to a valid pointer.
2. Initialize `b->a` to a valid pointer.
3. Initialize `b->a->var`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct a{
    int var;
}aa;

typedef struct b{
    aa *a;
}bb;

int main(void)
{
    bb *b;
    /* initialize b */
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
    if (b == NULL) return 1;
    /* initialize b->a */
    b->a = malloc(sizeof(*b->a));
    if (b->a == NULL)
    {
        free(b);
        return 1;
    }
    /* initialize b->a->var */
    b->a->var = 42;
    
    /* free what are allocated */
    free(b->a);
    free(b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Struct `a` is not nested in struct `b`, but struct `b` contains a pointer to a a struct a object.

The two objects' pointers can be initialized independently E.g.: First allocate memory for `a`, then allocate memory for `b`, and finally assign the memory allocated for `a` to `b->a`.
However, it would be better to allocate memory for `b` first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int var;
} aa;

typedef struct {
    aa *a;
} bb;

int main() {
    bb *b = (bb*) malloc(sizeof *b);
    b->a = (aa*) malloc(sizeof *(b->a));

    b->a->var = 5;
    printf("%d\n", b->a->var);

    free(b->a);
    free(b);
}
```

(Checking `malloc`'s return values omitted for brevity.)

Note the free'ing of memory in the reverse order. If `b` would have been free'd first, the pointer to `a` would have been lost.
Also, note how the typedef's do not declare an additional unused `struct a` and `struct b`.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value from `malloc`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @TimRandall Interesting, thanks! I've updated the code to the other variant of `sizeof`. There are arguments on both sides of the casting issue. For now I'm keeping the casts, as I find implicit casts a bigger evil than minor clutter/repetition.